# bash unpack multiple files

Tags: linux, bash, shell

so i given a compressed folder named files.zip and within this folder there are couple of folders with diferrent extantions like .txt .cmpr .gz .bz2 .zip.
i need to unpack all the folders recursively.
i start with this command:

```
$ find . -name "*zip" | while read filename; do 
    unzip -o-d "'dirname "$filename"'" "$filename"; 
done;
```

the command unpack the files.zip.
how sould i continue that all the folders within will be unpacking to.

thanks fo your help

Comment: Use backticks, not single quotes, to substitute a command output into the command line.

Comment: Better yet, use `$()` instead of backticks. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

Comment: The simplest way is to use `execdir` in `find` command.  `find . -name '*.zip' -execdir unzip {} \; `  the unzip command is run from the subdirectory containing the matched file,